# facing issues with my CakePHP 2 application not loading the webroot

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, phpdesktop

i'm using PHPDesktop to package a CakePHP 2 project and create a standalone desktop application but facing issues with my CakePHP 2 application not loading the webroot

reasons why did not webroot load and find solutions please

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the issue, we cannot guess the context just from a short, vague description. See also [ask]